# Apple Push Notification Service Limit

Tags: ios5, apple-push-notifications

Does apple have a limit on how many pushes can't be sent through APNS at once or in one day?

Answer (score 4):

Apple Push Notification Service is not limited by the number of notification to send.

Answer (score 0):

@Sam I had the same question and needed some written evidence about APNS being free to be demonstrated to the client. After failing to find any such declaration on the official site, I had written a mail to Developer Support and the crux of their response was "currently its a free service". So go ahead and send as many notifications as you want :)